# Script issue, won't allow me to run and use

Tags: javascript

i want to add this script to our google site and when i save the script it says syntax error on line 1 file "code". what am i doing wrong? is there a better way to add to the website beside creating a new script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d) {
    var mp = d.createElement('script'),
        h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    mp.type = 'text/javascript';
    mp.async = true;
    mp.src = 'http://www.maxpreps.com/includes/js/widget/widget.compressed.js';
    h.appendChild(mp);
})(document);
</script>
<a class="maxpreps-widget-link" data-width="500" data-height="600" data-item-count="10" data-type="wall" data-include-header="true" data-member-id="f1370c24-8591-481a-a380-fb1e53fab4a2" data-allow-scrollbar="true" href="http://www.maxpreps.com/local/school/home.aspx?schoolid=b76276a0-3880-4d40-83db-512ca9202efd" >Coleman Tech High School School Info</a>
```

Comment: Try giving the non minified version next time

Comment: **Don't** replace the first command with a semicolon, the only effect that will have is making `h` a global, which you don't want.

Comment: @raam86 That's not minified...?

Comment: Copy/pasting your code into a new page shows no problems. Whatever the issues are, they aren't with the code you've shown here. Possibly it has something to do with how you are "adding this script your google site". What do you mean by "google site"? How are you adding the script to it? Are you editing a file in a text editor and then uploading it with an FTP client (for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

This code looks okay. Perhaps the error is in the widget JS that you're loading?

Try loading the unminified version by removing the '.compressed'. That way it might be easier to see the problem as all the code won't be on one line.

```
(function (d) {
var mp = d.createElement('script'),
    h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
mp.type = 'text/javascript';
mp.async = true;
mp.src = 'http://www.maxpreps.com/includes/js/widget/widget.js';
h.appendChild(mp);
})(document);
```